# Imperfect digit-to-digit invariants in Base $10$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, exponentiation

$3435 = 3^3 + 4^4 + 3^3 + 5^5$ is an example of a [perfect digit-to-digit invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_digit-to-digit_invariant).

**Fact:** The number of PDDIs is finite for any given base; in particular, for base $10$.

**Question:** Working over base $10$, fix an integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and compute the sum $S_k$ as done above for $3435$ for every positive integer $k$. Must the union $\{k: S_k - n = k\} \cup \{k: S_k + n = k\}$ be finite?

(Note that the fact above says this union *is* finite when $n = 0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the number of digits of $k \in \mathbb N$.  Then $k \ge 10^{d-1}$, while $S_k \le 9^9 d$.  Notice that $S_k / k \to 0$ very quickly as $d$ increases, so for large $d$ it is impossible for $S_k$ to be remotely close to $k$.  That's why there are only finitely many PDDIs, and also why there are only finitely many occurrences of any fixed value of $k - S_k$.  For that matter, even the much larger set $\{k \in \mathbb N : S_k > k/n \}$ is finite for a given $n>0$.